# appending element only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I don't know how to append elements copy, embeded code and iframe only once to  container #link-options-dropdown.

My problem is that when I am clicking on .share-widget I am appending all elements again and again, I would like the elements to be appended only once.

```
 events: {
    'click .share-widget': 'showEmbededCode',
  },


showEmbededCode: function(e) {
        var emebededCode = '<div class="inframe-container"></div>';
        var widgetKey = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-widgetKey");
        var iframe = '<iframe src="'+widgetKey+'/widget" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
        var copy = '<p class="copy-widget">Copy and paste the code below to your blog or website. If needed adjust the width or/and height (f.e. width="400px"): </p>';
          $('#link-options-dropdown').append(copy);
          $('#link-options-dropdown').append(emebededCode);
          $('.inframe-container').text(iframe);    
      },
```

Comment: don't know about backbone event handlers... in jQuery instead of using `click` you can use `.one('click', function(){})` to register a handler which will run only once

Comment: use this line first $('#link-options-dropdown').html(''); on showEmbededCode function to reset the  html values in to the element and it will add again.

Comment: looks like you have [.on()](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) and [.off()](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) use them... in the `showEmbededCode` handler you can remove the handler using `.off()` so that it will be called only once

Comment: how should i use this off()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two majors options in going about this. You can check the state of the DOM which is good if you have something else that is likely to remove the child elements (like another View), or you can set a flag for the view which is many times more efficient (but harder to manage).

For checking the DOM:

```
events: {
  'click .share-widget': 'showEmbededCode'
},
showEmbededCode: function(e){
  /* Check to see if the copy-widget already exists as a child */
  if($("#link-options-dropdown .copy-widget").length===0){
    var emebededCode = '<div class="inframe-container"></div>';
    var widgetKey = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-widgetKey");
    var iframe = '<iframe src="'+widgetKey+'/widget" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    var copy = '<p class="copy-widget">Copy and paste the code below to your blog or website. If needed adjust the width or/and height (f.e. width="400px"): </p>';
    $('#link-options-dropdown').append(copy);
    $('#link-options-dropdown').append(emebededCode);
    $('.inframe-container').text(iframe);  
  }
}
```

For setting a flag:

```
initialize: function(){
  ...
  _.bindAll(this, "showEmbededCode");/* Makes sure `this` refers to View (Part of Underscore) */
},
events: {
  'click .share-widget': 'showEmbededCode'
},
embededCodeDrawn: false,
showEmbededCode: function(e){
  /* Check to see if the flag is set */
  if(this.embededCodeDrawn){
    var emebededCode = '<div class="inframe-container"></div>';
    var widgetKey = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-widgetKey");
    var iframe = '<iframe src="'+widgetKey+'/widget" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    var copy = '<p class="copy-widget">Copy and paste the code below to your blog or website. If needed adjust the width or/and height (f.e. width="400px"): </p>';
    $('#link-options-dropdown').append(copy);
    $('#link-options-dropdown').append(emebededCode);
    $('.inframe-container').text(iframe);
    this.embededCodeDrawn = true; /* Make sure it isn't drawn again */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
showEmbededCode: function(e) {
    $('#link-options-dropdown').html('');
                var emebededCode = '<div class="inframe-container"></div>';
                var widgetKey = $(e.currentTarget).attr("data-widgetKey");
                var iframe = '<iframe src="'+widgetKey+'/widget" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
                var copy = '<p class="copy-widget">Copy and paste the code below to your blog or website. If needed adjust the width or/and height (f.e. width="400px"): </p>';
                  $('#link-options-dropdown').append(copy);
                  $('#link-options-dropdown').append(emebededCode);
                  $('.inframe-container').text(iframe);    
              },
```

Comment: but is is not the only content on #link-options-dropdown